# How to find out which data I just imported into Oracle?

Tags: oracle, import

I imported two dump files (no idea what they contained, my goal is precisely to find out what they contain) into Oracle, but now I am struggling to identify what is the data I imported, and what data was originally there. On a fresh install of Oracle 11g.

The number of schemas does not seem to have changed, 37. I have browsed around and most of what I see seems to be Oracle's own data (note: I am an Oracle beginner).

To import, I use the first command for the first file, then the second because I was told by `imp` that DBA was needed for that file:

```
imp nico/nico file=C:\data\FILE1.DMP
imp system/thepassword file=C:\data\FILE2.DMP full=yes
```

Does the command line output of `imp` show the identifiers of all imported data?
Is there a sort of history logs where I can see which tables/rows have been imported recently?

I have spotted one imported table in `SYSTEM`, but would like to have an exhaustive list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using import with `show=y` won't actually do the import, but will show which tables the import will run against.  There's no practical way, however, to show what *rows* import will write; it's assumed that you, running the import, would know that.

You may wish to look at some of Oracle's [extensive documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/toc.htm) about these utilities to determine what options are available and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried impd.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php

Comment: Data Pump will only read files that were created with Data Pump.  If the files he has were created with the old Exp utility, then he needs to use Imp to import them.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to know what data you imprted would be a log miner session, which depending on the database use, it can be a daunting task

Answer (score 0):

Just add one extra column to the target table with Date/systimestamp datatype using defual systimestamp.

then you can easily find out the latest data.